# How to prevent an app version which is in review currently from being released automatically?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted a next version of my application to iTunesConnect for review. It is in review currently. And now for some reason I would like this version not to be released automatically once it is approved. I would like to release it myself when I want to. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Go To my app and click your app and in below you can see some option.you just select Release manually.So that you can get info from apple like "Pending developer version" once they accepts your app

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `https://itunesconnect.apple.com`
2. Insert 'Username/Password'
3. Click on `My Apps`
4. Click on your application icon.
5. click on `iOS APP`
6. Scroll bottom and `Version Release` where you can manage.

[image]

But please try all this step and confirm that I correct or not.